# Google Analytics - Cross Browser Tracking with jquery not adding cookie

Tags: jquery, cross-browser, google-analytics

I've setup our GA code to handle cross browser tracking across domains.

Our GA code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'firstdomain.com']);
_gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Error-404', 'page: ' + document.location.pathname + document.location.search,' ref: ' + document.referrer ]);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
</script>
```

The jQuery code that adds the onClick _link to  elements on page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Add onClick _link to all <a> elements on page where href contains sister sites
  $("a[href*='seconddomain.com'],a[href*='thirddomain.com'],a[href*='fourthdomain.com']").click(function() {
    _gaq.push(['_link', this.href]);
  return false;
});
```

The problem is, while I know you don't see the link change on the page, when you click on it, the cookie should be visible in the browser address field with the new link, but that isn't what is happening.

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing closing brackets and parens in your jQuery code.  You close out the `.click` function but not the `.ready` function.  Should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Add onClick _link to all <a> elements on page where href contains sister sites
 $("a[href*='seconddomain.com'],a[href*='thirddomain.com'],a[href*='fourthdomain.com']").click(function() {
    _gaq.push(['_link', this.href]);
    return false;
  });
}); // <-- missing this
```

**edit:**

Since you said this fix didn't work (note, you needed to do that anyways)...

Well I know the code itself works, I've tested it. So there is likely something else on your page, some condition or other code that is preventing it from executing.

Some things to check:

- *Are the links hardcoded or exist at the time the click listener is applied?*

If your links are dynamically generated (even if it's just the href attribs) sometime after the `.click` code is executed, then the event won't attach to the links.  To fix this, you need to do some delegated event listening instead of direct event listening.  Basically the idea is that you attach the event listener to some parent object that will exist from the start, and then filter for the links during the event bubbling. Here is an example of how to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on("click", "a[href*='seconddomain.com'],a[href*='thirddomain.com'],a[href*='fourthdomain.com']", function(event){
    _gaq.push(['_link', this.href]);
    return false;
  });
});
```

- *Perhaps the GA code doesn't have enough time to execute before the redirect..*

Try adding a `.preventDeafault` to suppress the normal redirect, then do a `.setTimeout` for like 500ms and then change `location.href` to the target URL.  Alternatively, try adding `target='_blank'` in the links to have them open in a new window/tab (since it will open in a new window, the question of "enough time to execute" becomes moot).  If either of these work, then you will know that GA isn't being given enough time to execute before the redirection, and you will need to do one of these things to ensure it has a chance to execute.

- *Perhaps you have other code that is overriding/overwriting the click event of the link(s)?*

[VisualEvent](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/visual+event+2) is a great bookmarklet for checking out events added to a link (or other elements).

Comment: Thanks Crayon. I closed the function, but I'm still not seeing the cookie in the URL address field when it clicks through.

Comment: Thanks Crayon. The redirect is the issue, although I wasn't able to get the passed cookie to display using .preventDefault and .setTimeout. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I'm kinda out of suggestions at this point, without looking at or being able to poke at your site :( at least you know the problem now, a step forward